# Form is using get instead of post, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular to post a form, I'm receiving the following error which is usually related to a get instead of a post, the problem is I've clearly told it to post. Any idea what the issue could be?

```
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

This is everything related to Angular and the form.

```
 var app = angular.module("scd",
['ngSanitize','ngMessages','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

 app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
 });

    app.controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.submitEmail = function()
        {
            $http.post('/learnmore', {data: $scope.learn_more_email});
        }

        $scope.submitContact = function()
        {
            $http.post('/contact', {data: $scope.contact});
        }       

 }]);
```

Comment: Have you checked the server to make sure that it's actually a GET request?

Comment: Yes. You can see here: http://i.imgur.com/ePfdDQj.png